# Shell script syntax error messsages "unexpected end of file" and "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `" ' "

Tags: shell-script

basically when I run my code i get two syntax errors. below:

```
./Qscript.sh: line 34: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./Qscript.sh: line 44: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

And when I fix those I still get some different errors?

```
#!/bin/bash
right=0
wrong=0
question=10
i=0
if [ $# -eq 2 ]
        then
for((i=0; 1<question;)) {
i=$(expr $i +1)
y=$i
echo "${awk "NR==$y" $1)"
        read -p "Enter Answer: " arg1
result=$(awk "NR==$y" $2)

if [ "$arg1" = "$result" ]
        then
right=`expr $right + 1`
else
wrong=`expr $wrong + 1`
fi
)
echo "Number_of_correct_answers " $right
echo "Number_of_wrong_answers " $wrong
fi

if [ $# -eq 3 ]
then
for((i=0; i<question;)) {
i=$(expr $i + 1)
y=$i
ans="$(awk "NR==$y" $2)"
resultfile=$(awk "NR==$y" $3)

if [ "$resultfile" = "$ans" ]
then
right=`expr $right + 1`
else
wrong=`expr $wrong + 1`
fi
)
echo $right
fi
```

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in your script. You should really be developing incrementally rather than trying to write everything in one go. Please paste it into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and start by correcting the first error. Then paste it in again and continue.

Comment: You have 3 errors in your code, viz. on lines 11, 20, and 40. On line 11, you need $( instead of ${ whereas on lines 20 and 40 you need a } rather than ).

Comment: Get yourself a good editor, like "gvim" with the syntax mode enabled. That would have immediately alerted to the point of errors.

Comment: The `for` loops lack both `do` and `done` too.

Comment: Bash also supports the traditional C-style for loops with braces as loop body delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of critique, in addition to the answers in the comments, may I suggest you try and adopt a technique of doing the following:

- placing variables within quotes:

`echo "Number_of_correct_answers ${right}"`

For example, this would help avoid problems where $right could expand in certain situations with undesirable effects.

- use `` rather than $()

Using ``, although it is not possible to nest in the same way that `$( $() )` can, backticks are backwardly compatible with /bin/sh which is slightly more available than /bin/bash (such as older solaris etc).

- don't try and nest ""

If possible, when you need to put quote in things such as awk, try using ' rather than ", if you really must, then a HEREDOC might be more appropriate.